# Проблема со слайдером и текстом

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Есть слайдер - как зафиксировать текст - чтобы при прокрутке он оставался внутри своего блока, и не двигался вместе с прокруткой.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pxar = 0;
  var n = $(".news-overflow").length;
  var pages = Math.floor(n / 3);
  var curPage = 0;

  $(".news-right").click(function() {
    if (curPage <= pages) {
      pxar -= 704;
      curPage++;
      $(".news-overflow").stop().animate({
        "margin-left": pxar + "px"
      }, 1000);
    }
  })

  $(".news-left").click(function() {
    if ((curPage - 1) >= 0) {
      pxar += 704;
      curPage--;
      $(".news-overflow").stop().animate({
        "margin-left": pxar + "px"
      }, 1000);
    }
  })

});
```

```css
.news-table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 260px;
  background: #0e0f16;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #171823;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.news-table-content {
  display: block;
  width: 1060px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 52px;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 35px;
}
.news-body {
  display: block;
  width: 98%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-body img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 340px;
}
ul.slider-footer li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.slider-footer li .news-slider-descr {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.slider-footer li img {
  width: 340px;
  height: 129px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.news-left {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  left: -18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 86px;
  background: #000;
}
.news-right {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  right: 56px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 43px;
  height: 86px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-table-content">
  <div class="news-body">
    <div class="news-overflow">
      <ul class="slider-footer">
        <li class="slider-item">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGckpST.jpg">
          <div class="news-slider-descr">
            Текст
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slider-item">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGckpST.jpg">
          <div class="news-slider-descr">
            Текст
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="slider-item">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGckpST.jpg">
          <div class="news-slider-descr">
            Текст
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="slider-item">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGckpST.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="slider-item">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LGckpST.jpg">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news-left"></div>
  <div class="news-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понял фразу "чтобы при прокрутке он оставался внутри своего блока, и не двигался вместе с прокруткой." Текст внутри блока, который двигается. Как ему остаться в своем блоке и не двигаться? Если вы хотите, все же, чтобы текст оставался на слайдах на своем месте и ездил с ними - добавьте родительским li `position:relative;` Если нет - уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо) Это было просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте

```
position: relative;
```

родительским (для текста) блокам `<li>`.

Дело в том, что при `position: absolute;` (как у ваших блоков с текстом) положение элемента вычисляется относительно ближайшего родителя с `position:absolute` или `position:relative` или относительно `body`. Так как Ближайшим родителем с указанными свойствами у вас является, если не ошибаюсь, `.news-table-content` то и позиционируется текст относительно него.